# Cartesian product of nested dictionaries of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I have some code that generates all the combinations for a dictionary of lists

```
import itertools
import collections

def gen_combinations(d):
    keys, values = d.keys(), d.values()
    combinations = itertools.product(*values)

    for c in combinations:
        yield dict(zip(keys, c))
```

Let's say I have a dictionary `A` like

```
A = {'a': [0, 1],
     'b': [2, 3, 4]}
```

It yields:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 2}
{'a': 0, 'b': 3}
{'a': 0, 'b': 4}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 3}
{'a': 1, 'b': 4}
```

Now I'd like it to work with nested dictionary of lists like

```
B = {'s1': {'a': [0, 1],
            'b': [0, 1, 2] },
     's2': {'c': [0, 1],
            'd': [0, 1] }}
```

which should yield something like:

```
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0},
 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}

{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0},
 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}

{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0},
 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}

{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0},
 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
```

and so on for all the combinations...
I'm looking for an elegant way to do this. Don't have any particular performance restrictions, they are small dictionaries.

Comment: Is this the deepest nesting level you would need or you are looking for a solution for an arbitrary number of nesting levels?

Comment: @jdehesa for my current use case that's the deepest nesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the product of the output of `gen_combinations()` for each key in the outer dictionary:

```
def gen_dict_combinations(d):
    keys, values = d.keys(), d.values()
    for c in itertools.product(*(gen_combinations(v) for v in values)):
        yield dict(zip(keys, c))
```

This is basically the same pattern, only now instead of using `values` directly, we use the output of `gen_combinations()`:

```
>>> for c in gen_dict_combinations(B):
...     print(c)
...
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ended up with a recursive version for arbitrarily nested dictionaries:

```
import itertools

def gen_combinations(d):
    keys, values = d.keys(), d.values()
    values_choices = (gen_combinations(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for v in values)
    for comb in itertools.product(*values_choices):
        yield dict(zip(keys, comb))


B = {'s1': {'a': [0, 1],
            'b': [0, 1, 2] },
     's2': {'c': [0, 1],
            'd': [0, 1] }}

for c in gen_combinations(B):
     print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 0, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 0}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 1}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 0, 'd': 1}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 0}}
{'s1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 's2': {'c': 1, 'd': 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I extended Martijn Pieters answer so that the function can also handle non-iterable values in the nested dictionary. So the code below works on nested dicts (just one level of nesting though) that look like this:

```
dictionary = {
    'a': 31415, 
    'b': 'strings too', 
    'c': [1, 2, 3], 
    'd': {'e': [1, 2, 3], 'f': 42, 'g': 'strings here too'}
}
```

```
from itertools import product

def _gen_combinations(d):
    keys, values = d.keys(), d.values()

    list_keys = [k for k in keys if isinstance(d[k], list)]
    nonlist_keys = [k for k in keys if k not in list_keys]
    list_values = [v for v in values if isinstance(v, list)]
    nonlist_values = [v for v in values if v not in list_values]

    combinations = product(*list_values)

    for c in combinations:
        result = dict(zip(list_keys, c))
        result.update({k: v for k, v in zip(nonlist_keys, nonlist_values)})
        yield result


def generate_dict_combinations(d):
    keys, values = d.keys(), d.values()

    dict_values = [v for v in values if isinstance(v, dict)]
    dict_keys = [k for k in keys if isinstance(d[k], dict)]
    nondict_values = [v for v in values if v not in dict_values]
    nondict_keys = [k for k in keys if k not in dict_keys]

    for c in product(*(_gen_combinations(v) for v in dict_values)):
        result = dict(zip(dict_keys, c))
        result.update({k: v for k, v in zip(nondict_keys, nondict_values)})
        yield result
```