# Python - is there a way to efficiently search for all objects with a particular attribute?

Tags: python, object, filter

**Context**
I have a script, which generates objects of the same class (this class is called `State`, for reference). Each object holds some `value` and the goal of the objects is to store and move values around. The other attributes of the objects are determined by a nested dictionary, such that the dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
    "foo":[1,2],
    "bar":{
        "baz":[3],
        "qux":[4]
        }
}
```

would produce 4 objects with the following attributes

```
self.foo = 1, self.bar.baz = 3, self.value = 0
self.foo = 1, self.bar.qux = 4, self.value = 0
self.foo = 2, self.bar.baz = 3, self.value = 0
self.foo = 2, self.bar.qux = 4, self.value = 0
```

(more information on this process here: [Combination of nested dictionaries with arbitrary lengths in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178819/combination-of-nested-dictionaries-with-arbitrary-lengths-in-python))

**Problem**
I need to find some way of finding all the objects that have a certain attribute, or set of attributes. For example, all the objects with the attribute `self.bar.baz` may need to take on a certain `value`, and `self.bar.qux` need to take on some other `value`.

**One potential solution**
One solution, is to create a separate object (from the `Environment` class, for reference), which is responsible for creating a list of all instantiated objects.

The simplest solution, is append all the objects to a list, and then loop through that list, checking which objects have a set of attributes. However, this gets inefficient very quickly, especially considering the set of objects is typically much more complex than the example above.

A slightly more advanced solution, is for the `Environment` object to have all possible attributes e.g.

```
self.foo
self.bar.baz
self.bar.qux
```

And the values of these attributes are lists, containing all objects with these attributes. This way, there is no need to filter through the list objects, and objects with a set of attributes can be filtered by returning the set of objects in two or more lists.

However, I'm not sure:

- What the code for this would actually look like?
- If there is a more efficient solution?

**Additional constraints**
Importantly, the attributes that `State` objects have, are not fixed. That is, it may not be `foo` and `bar` (or `baz` or `qux`), but may be completely different keys. Therefore, I cannot hardcode the attributes to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal :

```py
# creating data to use ...

class State:
    """Dummy class for State, the `name` member and the `__repr__` are for visualization purposes"""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


# creating fake data (according to the structure you provided, though)
s1, s2, s3, s4 = State("S1"), State("S2"), State("S3"), State("S4")
s1.foo = 1; s1.bar = State(""); s1.bar.baz = 3; s1.value = 0
s2.foo = 1; s2.bar = State(""); s2.bar.qux = 4; s2.value = 0
s3.foo = 2; s3.bar = State(""); s3.bar.baz = 3; s3.value = 0
s4.foo = 2; s4.bar = State(""); s4.bar.qux = 4; s4.value = 0

states = [s1, s2, s3, s4]


# now solving the problem ...

def recursively_has_attr(obj, attrs: str) -> bool:
    """Iterate over an object members to check whether is has an 'a.b.c' attribute."""
    for attr_name in attrs.split("."):
        if hasattr(obj, attr_name):
            obj = getattr(obj, attr_name)
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True


# we are going to create customized versions of the function `recursively_has_attr`
# by pre-filling its `attrs` parameters, using `functools.partial`
from functools import partial
matching_foo = partial(recursively_has_attr, attrs="foo")
matching_bar_baz = partial(recursively_has_attr, attrs="bar.baz")
matching_bar_qux = partial(recursively_has_attr, attrs="bar.qux")
matching_bar_zod = partial(recursively_has_attr, attrs="bar.zod")

print(f"matching foo : {tuple(filter(matching_foo, states))}")
print(f"matching bar.baz : {tuple(filter(matching_bar_baz, states))}")
print(f"matching bar.qux : {tuple(filter(matching_bar_qux, states))}")
print(f"matching bar.zod : {tuple(filter(matching_bar_zod, states))}")

user_supplied_attrs = input("Enter the attribute you want to search : ")
filtering_function = partial(recursively_has_attr, attrs=user_supplied_attrs)
print(f"matching {user_supplied_attrs!r} : {tuple(filter(filtering_function, states))}")
```

produces :

```py
matching foo : (S1, S2, S3, S4)
matching bar.baz : (S1, S3)
matching bar.qux : (S2, S4)
matching bar.zod : ()
Enter the attribute you want to search : bar
matching 'bar' : (S1, S2, S3, S4)
```

This works, other approaches can too.

As for being efficient, is it really a requirement ?
If yes, what do you mean by `efficient` ? Ii it memory-wise, speed-wise, line-of-code-wise, complexity-wise ?
If you want very good performance, would you consider using a lower-level language ? Cython for having "true" arrays ?

Test my approach on your data, and if it is not sufficient, please post a question with a clear goal :)

Comment: Apologies for not clearly specifying the goal, and I appreciate the response.

Comment: Apologies for not clearly specifying the goal, and I appreciate the response.

This solution is very close to what is needed. However, I would also need to match the values of attributes. e.g. `partial(recursively_has_attr, attrs="bar.baz.3"`

In the real example, the values of these attributes are strings. e.g. self.disease = "breast cancer", or self.disease = "diabetes". So the function would need to be able to find all objects which had disease = "diabetes", or disease = "breast cancer", and not just all objects with the attribute "disease".

Comment: Do you control the input format ? It would be simpler and cleaner to have something like `bar.baz=3` because it makes clear which are attributes and what is the expected value. On the contrary, having `bar.baz.3` you have to wonder if `3` is the name of an attribute that must exist or if `3` is the value of the `baz` attribute ? Or both could be possible ?